# How to unix pipe the output of one command into Elixir's Mix Task?

Tags: elixir, stdin, elixir-mix

I want to "pipe" the output of the `cat` command into an Elixir Mix Task and hold it in a variable as a binary.

I have already tried using the `IO.gets/1`, but it reads just the first line of the output.

```sh
cat textfile.txt | mix print
```

```rb
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Print do
  use Mix.Task

  def run(_argv) do
    Task.async(fn -> IO.gets("") end)
    |> Task.await(t)
    |> IO.puts() # prints the first line
  end
end
```

I want to get hold of the whole file's contents in a binary variable in Elixir and print it to the console, but I get just the first line. I'd expect Elixir to have some built-in solution, to end on EOF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [IO.read/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#read/2) function I was looking for.

```rb
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Print do
  use Mix.Task

  def run(_argv) do
    IO.read(:all)
    |> IO.puts() # prints all lines
  end
end
```